# How to maintain a particular value in boolean after the program has been stopped?

Tags: java, boolean

I have created a class variable as follows

```
private boolean xyz = false;
```

After which I am calling a method that will do some stuff and then change the value of the boolean variable to `true`.

Now the next time when I re-run the code the boolean value doesn't stay as true it goes back to false.

I want it to stay as true even if i close my program and then run it again later.

Answer (score 6):

> I want it to stay as true even if i close my program and then run it again later.

Well, that means you need to persist it somewhere.

Options include:

- Somewhere online
- A database
- User preferences via the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API
- A simple file in a well-known location

Basically, you'll need to write the data out *somewhere*, and read it back in on start-up. It's hard to give any more specific advice without more context.

Comment: I currently have two methods Method1 and Method2. I have another piece of code that calls these two methods. The logic is that if the boolean value is False then Method1 will be called and it will then set the boolean value to True.

Right now when I re run the code the boolean value if false and so Method1 is called everytime !!!

So the next time when i run the code the boolean should be true and Method2 should be called. 

therefore Method1 will only be called once.

Comment: @Nisarg: Yes, if you're rerunning in a fresh process which hasn't done any of the things in my answer, you *will* "forget" the result. That's why I gave the answer I did.

Comment: ok. i will try through one of the options as you suggested !! thanks a lot for your help..

Answer (score 0):

When you are exiting your program, use below to save your variable to a file in a location of your own, preferably, local directory of the program. It is called *serialization*.

```
try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("xyz.ser");//this saves to the directory where your program runs in
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(xyz);
         out.close();
          fileOut.close();
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Then, when you start your program, you can read it back with below code. This is called *deserialization*.

```
try
         {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("xyz.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            xyz = (boolean) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {// you are here if xyz.ser does not exist
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

You also might want to check if the file was created previously, otherwise, you will catch an IOException. You can do it by creating a File object with filename xyz.ser and calling exists() on it.

Comment: So what if the the file exists. I mean to say the second time when i run the program the file will already be there and so file.exists() == True. Then what should I do, should I still create fileoutputstream and objectoutputstream objects ??

Comment: You can execute the serialization part without worry, because it will automatically create the file for you and overwrite it for the second time and so on. For desereialization, when you are reading back the variable, if the file exists, you should do what is to be done, if not -> it is the first time your program is running so do nothing and save the variable at exit. Next time, the file will be there and you can read it back.